# I can't find why I can't pass data to props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't find why I can't pass data to props

In the Home component of index.js Pass props data to the PostCard component.
PostCard uses this to set property values.

But an error occurs.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nickname' of undefined
PostCard
./components/PostCard.js:19
  16 |  extra={<Button>팔로우</Button>}
  17 | >
  18 |  <Card.Meta
> 19 |      avatar={<Avatar>{post.User.nickname[0]}</Avatar>}
     | ^  20 |      title={post.User.nickname}
  21 |      description={post.content}
  22 |  />
```

i don't know why this error is occured

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Card, Icon, Button, Avatar } from 'antd'


const PostCard = (post) => {
    return (
        <Card
            key={+post.createdAt}
            cover={post.img && <img src={c.img} alt="example" />}
            actions={[
                <Icon type="retweet" key="retweet" />,
                <Icon type="heart" key="heart" />,
                <Icon type="message" key="message" />,
                <Icon type="ellipsis" key="ellipsis" />
            ]}
            extra={<Button>팔로우</Button>}
        >
            <Card.Meta
                avatar={<Avatar>{post.User.nickname[0]}</Avatar>}
                title={post.User.nickname}
                description={post.content}
            />
        </Card>
    );
};

export default PostCard;
```

PostCard.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Card, Icon, Button, Avatar } from 'antd'


const PostCard = (post) => {
    return (
        <Card
            key={+post.createdAt}
            cover={post.img && <img src={c.img} alt="example" />}
            actions={[
                <Icon type="retweet" key="retweet" />,
                <Icon type="heart" key="heart" />,
                <Icon type="message" key="message" />,
                <Icon type="ellipsis" key="ellipsis" />
            ]}
            extra={<Button>팔로우</Button>}
        >
            <Card.Meta
                avatar={<Avatar>{post.User.nickname[0]}</Avatar>}
                title={post.User.nickname}
                description={post.content}
            />
        </Card>
    );
};

export default PostCard;
```

This is a rudimentary question
but I can't find the cause of the error myself.
Is the props malformed?
I can't find the cause even if I look closely
Thank you very much for telling me how to fix this.

Comment: `postcard.js` and `index.js` are identical, please fix. You'll get this error if `User` is not defined: `post.User.nickname`. Please add json example of `post` that you pass to the component.

Comment: User was defined

I think that wasn't wrong.

The bottom person let me know and solved the error

The solution was (post) => ({post}).

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this,

```
const PostCard = (post) => {
```

You need to destructure `props` like,

```
const PostCard = ({post}) => {   //Notice the cruly braces
```

[Destructuring Props in React](https://medium.com/@lcriswell/destructuring-props-in-react-b1c295005ce0)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

The error is resolved

I shouldn't have made this mistake

Thank you

Thank you